# Speed up bash for loop which contains multiple sed commands

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

my bash for loop looks like:

```
for i in read_* ; do 
    cut -f1 $i | sponge $i
    sed -i '1 s/^/>/g' $i
    sed -i '3 s/^/>ref\n/g' $i
    sed -i '4d' $i
    sed -i '1h;2H;1,2d;4G' $i
    mv $i $i.fasta
done
```

Are there any methods of speeding up this process, perhaps using GNU `parallel?`

EDIT: Added input and expected output.

Input:

```
sampleid    97  stuff   2086    42  213M    =   3322    1431
TATTTAGGGAAGATCTGGCCTTCCTACAAGGGAAGGCCAGGGAATTTTCTTCAGAGCAGA
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
TTTTTAGGGAAGATCTGGCCTTCCTACAAGGGAAGGCCAGGGAATTTTCTTCAGAGCAGA
```

Hopeful output:

```
>ref
TTTTTAGGGAAGATCTGGCCTTCCTACAAGGGAAGGCCAGGGAATTTTCTTCAGAGCAGA
>sampleid
TATTTAGGGAAGATCTGGCCTTCCTACAAGGGAAGGCCAGGGAATTTTCTTCAGAGCAGA
```

I used the  `sed -i '1h;2H;1,2d;4G' $i` command to swap lines 2 and 4.

Comment: You might have a look at the `-e` option with `sed`.  You may be able to  combine your `sed` commands into a single `sed` command.  That said, it may not provide the performance gain you are seeking as it is still running as subprocess in a loop. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97428/sed-how-to-do-several-consecutive-substitutions-but-process-file-only-once for examples.

Comment: It's not clear you should use `sed` for this in the first place. `sed -i` usually means you should use `ed` instead, the original *file* editor from which the *stream* editor `sed` was derived.

Comment: Please ensure you provide a proper [mcve] with representative data.

Comment: Are the files always only 4 lines?

Comment: Yes always 4 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read it right, this should create the same result, though it would probably help a LOT if I could see what your input and expected output look like...

```
awk '{$0=$1}
     FNR==1{hd=">"$0; next}
     FNR==2{hd=hd"\n"$0;next}
     FNR==3{print ">ref\n"$0 > FILENAME".fasta"}
     FNR==4{next}
     FNR==5{print hd"\n"$0 > FILENAME".fasta"}
' read_*
```

My input files:

```
$: cat read_x
foo x
bar x
baz x
last x
curiosity x

$: cat read_y
FOO y
BAR y
BAZ y
LAST y
CURIOSITY y
```

and the resulting output files:

```
$: cat read_x.fasta
>ref
baz
>foo
bar
curiosity

$: cat read_y.fasta
>ref
BAZ
>FOO
BAR
CURIOSITY
```

This runs in one pass with no loop aside from `awk`'s usual internals, and leaves the originals in place so you can check it first. If all is good, all that's left is to remove the originals. For that, I would use extended globbing.

```
$: shopt -s extglob; rm read_!(*.fasta)
```

That will clean up the original inputs but not the new outputs.
Same results, three commands, no loops.

I am, or course, making some assumptions about what you are meaning to do that might not be accurate. To get this format in a single `sed` call -

```
$: sed -e 's/[[:space:]].*//' -e '1{s/^/>/;h;d}' -e '2{H;s/.*/>ref/}' -e '4x' read_x
>ref
baz
>foo
bar
curiosity
```

but that's not the same commands you used, so maybe I'm misreading it.

To use this to in-place edit multiple files at a time (instead of calling it in a loop on each file), use `-si` so that the line numbers apply to each *file* rather than the stream of records they *collectively* produce.

DON'T use `-is`, though you could use `-i -s`.

```
$: sed -s -i -e 's/[[:space:]].*//' -e '1{s/^/>/;h;d}' -e '2{H;s/.*/>ref/}' -e '4x' read_*
```

This still leaves you with the issue of renaming each, but `xargs` makes that pretty easy in the given example.

```
printf "%s\n" read_* | xargs -I@ mv @ @.fasta
```

## addendum

Using the file you gave in the OP, assuming every file is the same general structure and exactly 4 lines -

```
$: cat file_0 # I made files 0 through 7, but with same data
sampleid    97  stuff   2086    42  213M    =   3322    1431
TATTTAGGGAAGATCTGGCCTTCCTACAAGGGAAGGCCAGGGAATTTTCTTCAGAGCAGA
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
TTTTTAGGGAAGATCTGGCCTTCCTACAAGGGAAGGCCAGGGAATTTTCTTCAGAGCAGA

$: sed -Esi '1{s/^([^[:space:]]+).*/>\1/;h;s/.*/>ref/}; 3x;' file_?

$: cat file_0 # used a diff on each, worked on all at once
>ref
TATTTAGGGAAGATCTGGCCTTCCTACAAGGGAAGGCCAGGGAATTTTCTTCAGAGCAGA
>sampleid
TTTTTAGGGAAGATCTGGCCTTCCTACAAGGGAAGGCCAGGGAATTTTCTTCAGAGCAGA
```

Breakout:

`-Esi` `E`xtended pattern matching, `s`eparate file linecounts, `i`n-place edits
`1{...};` Collectively do these commands, in order, only on every line 1

- `s/^([^[:space:]]+).*/>\1/` add leading `>` but strip everything after any whitespace
- `h` store the resulting `>\1` line in the `h`old buffer
- `s/.*/>ref/` then replace the whole line with a literal `>ref`
  `3x' swap line 3 with the value in the hold buffer from line 1

`file_?` I used a glob to supply the appropriate list of files all at once.

Doing same with `awk`:

```
$: awk 'FNR==1{id=">"$1; print ">ref" >FILENAME".fasta"; next} FNR==3{print id > FILENAME".fasta"; next} {print $0 > FILENAME".fasta"}'  file_?
```

Then you can do file management as above with the `xargs`/`mv` for the `sed` or the `shopt`/`rm` for the `awk` - or we could add a little organizational work *in* `awk` if you like. Consider this:

```
awk 'BEGIN  { system(" mkdir -p done ") }
     FNR==1 { id=">"$1; print ">ref" > FILENAME".fasta"; next } # skip printing original
     FNR==3 {           print id     > FILENAME".fasta"; next } # skip printing original
            {           print $0     > FILENAME".fasta"       } # every line NOT skipped
     FNR==4 { close(FILENAME); close(FILENAME".fasta");
              system("mv " FILENAME " done/")
            }' file_?
```

Then if there are any problems, it's easy to delete the fasta's, move the originals back, adjust the code, and try again. If everything is ok, it's fast and easy to `rm -fr done`, yes?

Note that I really only added the `mkdir` inside a `system` call in the `awk` to show that you can, and to keep from having to manually do it separately if you have to run a few iterations or move it all into a wrapper script, etc.

Comment: Thankyou for your brilliant answer, I have added the input and expected output to my question. I will adapt the awk command you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question runs multiple subprocesses (`cut`, `sponge`, `sed` four times, and `mv`) for each file that is processed.  Running subprocesses is relatively slow, so you can speed up the code significantly by reducing the number of them.

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code is one way to do it:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

old_files=()
for f in read_* ; do 
    readarray -t lines <"$f"
    printf '>ref\n%s\n>%s\n%s\n'    \
        "${lines[3]}" "${lines[0]%%[[:space:]]*}" "${lines[1]}" >"$f.fasta"
    old_files+=( "$f" )
done 
rm -- "${old_files[@]}"
```

- This runs no subprocesses when processing individual files.  It just reads the lines of the old file into an array using the built-in `readarray` command and writes to the new file using the built-in `printf`.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of the `%%` in `${lines[0]%%[[:space:]]*}`.
- To avoid running `rm` for each file, the code keeps a list of files to be deleted and removes all of them at the end.  If you try the code, consider commenting the `rm` line until you are very confident that the rest of the code is doing what you want.